# Parsing YAML file to gather certain data

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am completely new to .yaml and python. I am trying to figure out how to parse data from yaml to gather certain data that I need and write it to a different file.

```
Checking Information:
- Time Stamp: ['2014-10-20 17:10:16', '2014-10-20 17:16:10']
  Unique Number: 60025893
  Accept/Reject: 'Yes'
  Policy ID: '01693'
  Specific name: Axis-447
- Time Stamp: ['2014-10-20 18:10:56', '2014-10-20 18:15:53']
  Unique Number: 15832596
  Accept/Reject: 'No'
  Policy ID: '68975'
  Specific name: Axis-533
```

Above shows part of my yaml file. I want to try and extract policy id and specific name and code below shows what I was able to come up with so far.

```
with open("test.yaml", "r") as f: 
    doc = yaml.load(f)
    txt = doc['Checking Information']['Specific name']
    print(txt)
```

It would be much appreciated, if anyone could help me out with it.

Comment: How do you get `doc`? It seems to me you need to read the contents of `f`, pass it to a YAML function to read it and turn it into `doc`.

Comment: oh I missed one line from my code. I have edited my question. I used the yaml.load to get doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc['Checking Information']` is actually an array. You will need to loop through the array before you access individual keys.

Try:

```
txt = doc['Checking Information']
for element in txt:
    print(element['Specific name'])
```